# What does it mean by "read/write variable" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I am reading book JavaScript: The Definitive Guide.

In section 3.4, it says,

> In ECMAScript 3, undefined is a read/write variable, and it can be set
>   to any value. This error is corrected in ECMAScript 5 and undefined is
>   read-only in that version of the language.

what exactly does it mean by a read/write variable?

Comment: means you could do `undefined = "HAHA"` and now you can not.

Comment: It means a variable you can read from and write to. So you could set `undefined = "this is a bad idea"`.

Comment: means that some variable can be changed and some of them cannot be as `undefined`, `null` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is "read/write", it means you can both read it and write to it. Contrast with a read-only variable (you can't write to it), or a write-only variable (you can't read from it; fairly unusual, but entirely possible).

In JavaScript, variables are read/write by default. In fact, until ES2015, all true variables were read/write. In ES2018, we got `const`, which lets you create a "variable" that's read-only ("constant"), but it's still a "variable" (what the spec calls a *binding*) in all other ways.

But it was (and is) possible to create read-only global "variables" even before `const`, by creating a read-only *property* of the global object:

```js
// A global scope, this refers to the global object
Object.defineProperty(this, "answer", {
  value: 42,
  writable: false // this is the default, including it here for emphasis
});
console.log("answer = ", answer); // 42
answer = 67; // Would be an error in strict mode
console.log("answer = ", answer); // still 42
```

That works because properties of the global object are accessible as global variables.

Answer (score 2):

A read/write variable means a variable to which you can assign some value and later on read the same eg

```
var x = 10; writing to it
console.log(x) //prints 10  -- reading from it
```

Uptill ECMAScript 3, "undefined" was a r/w variable i.e you can do undefined="foo", which makes no sense.